# Rails render Json only if it contains parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, api

I'm playing with the Groupon API. Using rails, how would I display only the Json results that contain certain parameters set by user.

For example, if a user only wanted to see deals that contain "sky diving" in them. Or an easier example would be, only if the valid_deal: true.

Comment: what's wrong with parsing the json result?

Comment: @phoet - nothing, I just want to filter the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Parse the Json and that would give a hash or array object
2. Create a new object with the results you want from the above hash. If you want to retain most results and just want to remove some, you can just remove some elements of the same object.
3. Render back the object in step 2 created as json

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get a json object from the API?

To parse the json into a more usable hash, use

```
deals_hash = your_json['deals']
```

To get all the deals from the hash where valid_deal = true

```
deals_hash.select{|deal| deal['valid_deal'] == true}
```

you may have to use "true" depending on if the type is considered a string or boolean by ruby.

As for searching, I would store all the deals in a database, and use a full text search gem, such as solr or acts_as_indexed.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I was able to get my json object. There are about 70 daily deals so I am trying to filter them.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the json object as requires and display the results in hash/array.

There would be options to pass parameters to groupon Api which would return results containing those parameters.

Loop through the hash to pull the specific parameters which you want to display.